# i am trying to use count() function in laravel but i am running in to this error syntax error, unexpected 'count' (T_STRING)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

here is where i am using this function

```
@if($tags count() > 0)
<div class="form-group">
<label for="tags">Tags</label>

<select   name="tags"  id="tags" class="form-control" multiple>

    @foreach ($tags as $tag)

    <option value="{{$tag->id}}">
    {{$tag->name}}
    </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif
```

here in my controller i am using tags as key in my controller as

```
 public function index()
    {
        //
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts',Post::all())->with('tags',Tag::all());
    }
```

i am running into this error quite often when ever the count==0 then this error appears which says syntax error, unexpected 'count' (T_STRING)
any idea how i can remove this 
i am learner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the tag variable is set or not and then count afterwards

```
@if(isset($tags) && count($tags) > 0)
<div class="form-group">
<label for="tags">Tags</label>

<select   name="tags"  id="tags" class="form-control" multiple>

    @foreach ($tags as $tag)

    <option value="{{$tag->id}}">
    {{$tag->name}}
    </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif
```